# How to update modal component with new props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a modal component for saving recipes to a list.

```
 modal = <Modal saveRecipe={this.saveRecipe} closeModal={this.toggleModal}/>
```

Also I want to use this same modal component to edit the recipe, so i do this

```
if(this.state.editItem){
  modal = <Modal content={editContent} saveRecipe={this.saveRecipe} closeModal={this.toggleModal}/>
  }
else{
  modal = <Modal saveRecipe={this.saveRecipe} closeModal={this.toggleModal}/>
}
```

so I'm able to pass down the object to be edited to Modal Component.
The modal component has a text input and a textarea element.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {dish: '', ingredients:[]};      
}
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){ 
  console.log(nextProps) // Never fired..why??     
  let {dish, ingredients} = nextProps.content
  this.setState({
    dish:dish, ingredients:ingredients
  })
}
render(){
  let {dish, ingredients} = this.state
  console.log(this.props) // {dish:"new dish", ingredients:['ingreds']}
  return(
   <div className="modal">
    <input type="text" ref="title" value={dish} />
    <textarea ref="ingredients" value={ingredients}></textarea>
   </div>
   )
```

I want to prepopulate the modal form elements when edit is clicked. I am able to populate the input and textarea field if I provide

```
let {dish, ingredients} = this.props
```

instead of `this.state`. But then the form field become uneditable. So referring to [forms](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html), I am trying to change state of Modal Component. In my code `componentWillReceiveProps` is never fired? How does the componentWillRecieveProps work exactly in this situation? How to update modal component with new props?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you have to use `componentDidMount` because when `editItem` state is set, then you are unmounting `Model` component and remounting it with `content` prop. So in that case `componentWillRecceiveProps` will not get fired but `componentDidMount` will get fired. So move your `componentWillReceiveProps` logic to `componentDidMount` like

```
componentDidMount(){ 
  console.log(this.props) // Never fired..why??     
  let {dish, ingredients} = this.props.content
  this.setState({
    dish:dish, ingredients:ingredients
  })
}
```